# Not able to sort array of strings taken as input from user

Tags: java

I am trying to obtain the array of strings from user and then trying to sort it alphabetically.But it is not responding after giving output for line given below :-

System.out.println("Array is"+Arrays.toString(Arr));

Below is the code used for this:-

```
package practice1;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RemDup {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
        //Obtaining array from user and sorting it
        List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            System.out.println("Current list is"+list);
            System.out.println("Add more(y/n)");
            if (in.next().startsWith("y")) {
                System.out.println("Enter:");
                list.add(in.next());
            }else{break;

            }
        } while (true);
        System.out.println("List is "+list);
        String[] Arr=list.toArray(new String[0]);
        System.out.println("Array is"+Arrays.toString(Arr));
        String str=Arr.toString();
        String[] strArr=str.split(" ");
        for(int i=0;i<Arr.length;i++)
        {
            for (int j = i+1; j < Arr.length; j++) {
                if (strArr[i].compareTo(strArr[j])>0) {
                    String temp=strArr[i];
                    strArr[i]=strArr[j];
                    strArr[j]=temp;
                }
            }
        }
        for(String ss:strArr){
            System.out.println(ss);
        }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.toString();
        }
    }

}
```

Please help

Comment: Should indicate whether you are allowed to use `Collections.sort`. Assuming not, but explicit clarification is always nice. Also, I don't think `Arr.toString()` is giving you what you think it is.

Comment: Try using `Arrays.asList(Arr)` and let me know if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is  with the following lines

```
    String str=Arr.toString();
    String[] strArr=str.split(" ");
```

toString doesn't return value which you expected.

Just replace these tw line by following
        String[] strArr=list.toArray(new String[0]);

Answer (score 0):

Your code is throwing java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. You may not be realizing that as your catch block does nothing. Try printing e in the catch block. Because of the exception, your code is not getting executed beyond the for loop

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code, which will work for you,

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RemDup {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Obtaining array from user and sorting it
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            do {
                System.out.println("Current list is" + list);
                System.out.println("Add more(y/n)");
                if (in.next().startsWith("y")) {
                    System.out.println("Enter:");
                    list.add(in.next());
                } else {
                    break;

                }
            } while (true);
            System.out.println("List is " + list);
            String[] Arr = list.toArray(new String[0]);
            System.out.println("Array is" + Arrays.toString(Arr));
            String str = Arr.toString();
            Arrays.sort(Arr);
            System.out.println("Sorted Array is" + Arrays.toString(Arr));           
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Sample out put :
Current list is[]

Add more(y/n)y

Enter:aaa

Current list is[aaa]

Add more(y/n)

y

Enter:

hhh

Current list is[aaa, hhh]

Add more(y/n)

y

Enter:

ccc
Current list is[aaa, hhh, ccc]
Add more(y/n)
y
Enter:

123
Current list is[aaa, hhh, ccc, 123]
Add more(y/n)

n
List is [aaa, hhh, ccc, 123]

Array is[aaa, hhh, ccc, 123]

Sorted Array is[123, aaa, ccc, hhh]

Answer (score 0):

Your code is throwing ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

```
    String str=Arr.toString();
    String[] strArr=str.split(" ");
```

These doesnot makes sense in your scope

Try this :

```
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.Arrays;
        import java.util.List;
        import java.util.Scanner;

        public class SortTest {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
        //Obtaining array from user and sorting it
        List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            System.out.println("Current list is"+list);
            System.out.println("Add more(y/n)");
            if (in.next().startsWith("y")) {
                System.out.println("Enter:");
                list.add(in.next());
            }else{break;

            }
        } while (true);

        System.out.println("List is "+list);
        String[] Arr=list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
        System.out.println("Array is"+Arrays.toString(Arr));
        String[] strArr=new String[Arr.length];
        for(int i=0;i<Arr.length;i++)
        {
            for (int j = i+1; j < Arr.length; j++) {
                if (Arr[i].trim().compareTo(Arr[j].trim())>0) {
                    String temp=Arr[j];
                    Arr[j]=Arr[i];
                    Arr[i]=temp;
                }
            }
            strArr[i]=Arr[i];
        }
        System.out.println("After sorting : ");
        for(String ss:strArr){
            System.out.print(ss + " ");
        }
     }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    }

    }
```